# Regular expression to find content that is sandwitched between 2 symbols

Tags: javascript, regular-expressions

This might have been asked before but I cant find a solution. I am looking for a simple "Regular Expressions" search pattern to find something in my PHP files.

I am looking for the following pattern

```
<?php
$_yilyjcr = '
```

However, the "_yilyjcr" can be different or longer or shorter. Sometimes have a symbol and sometimes not
So the goal would be to search in EMEditor using a reguklar expression that looks for

```
<?php
$_yilyjcr = 'm#cs9lrf8eoxH\'0n4tg7vu_ap*kb-361dyi5';$edfflw = Array();$edfflw[] = $yilyjcr[2].$yilyjcr[6].$yilyjcr[9].$yilyjcr[23].$
```

Would anyone maybe have a tip for me what search pattern I could use to find files that contain this?
I would be really appriciate any assistance.

Best wishes,
Thomas

Comment: I'm no expert in regex but I came out with this that matches the pattern that you've provided `^\<\?php\n^\$[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s=.*$` I'm sure someone will find a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: You should use a site like `https://regexr.com` to build your regular expression.

Comment: @Tero-Kilkanen I did try regerx.com for this but I cant get it done.

Comment: @BANJOSA thank you for this but it does not work. I tryed this in regexr.com using the code below as sample. but it fdoes not find it.

`<?php
$_yilyjcr = 'm#cs9lrf8eoxH\'0n4tg7vu_ap*kb-361dyi5';$edfflw = Array();$edfflw[] = $yilyjcr[2].$yilyjcr[6].$yilyjcr[9].$yilyjcr[23].$`

Comment: Please edit the original question when adding extra information, it is difficult to read from comments.

Comment: @Thom of course it doesn't work, that was not the sample you've provided in the question. in you question. that regex was tailored to capture what you've provided as an example. Please had a real example to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help, you both have broght me on the right track.
I have edited the original question. However, I have figured it out.

I did use:

```
\<\?.{3}\n\$.{5,8}\s\=\s.{30,50}\;\$[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,8}\s\=\s[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}\(\)
```

that found all instances for this.